# Building a function for excel that returns a string

Tags: vba, excel

I'm practicing building functions that are used as formula's in cells and seem to have hit a snag.   The code below works as long as it is not returning a string while being used in a cell.  This code works perfectly for integers and even works with strings when I've coded a sub to use the function.  I can't seem to figure out why when i use it in a formula in a cell it returns

```
Function bIsBlank(x As String) As String

Dim y As String

If x = "" Then  'check to see if it is blank
    Exit Function
Else 
    y = Evaluate(x) 'solve the formula that is pulled in

    If y = "0" Then 'check to see if formula equals zero
        y = ""      'set to nothing if it is zero
    End If
End If

    'below is my attempt to fix it by adding quotes on either side of the string
    'this did not work
    y = Chr(34) & y & Chr(34)

'this seems to solve for a sub but not a formula in a cell for strings
bIsBlank = y

End Function
```

---

The issue is that i didn't need to use the evaluate function.   The formula i was pulling in was already solved.   So say i had a vlookup that solved for "A".  In the code X = "A" not the string vlookup(a1,a5:b10,2,0) as I originally expected

Comment: *I can't seem to figure out why when i use it in a formula in a cell it returns*? you missed out something? :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your code?

Answer (score 0):

`1.` Always use `Option Explicit`

`2.` `String` is value type and can't be a `Null` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Function bIsBlank(Optional x As String) As String
    Dim y As String

    bIsBlank = ""

    If x = "" Then Exit Function

    y = Application.Evaluate(x)

    If y = 0 Then bIsBlank = "" Else _
    bIsBlank = y
End Function
```

**Various Scenarios**

[image]

[image]

**NOTE**: Once you enter the formula and then you change the values in the cells say `A1:A10`, the `bIsBlank()` won't calculate automatically. You have to use `Application.Volatile` for that. See example below

```
Option Explicit

Function bIsBlank(Optional x As String) As String
    Dim y As String

    Application.Volatile

    bIsBlank = ""

    If x = "" Then Exit Function

    y = Application.Evaluate(x)

    If y = 0 Then bIsBlank = "" Else _
    bIsBlank = y
End Function
```